# ssas measure expression alternative in standard edition

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I have a standard fact sales table (FactTransaction, one row per article),
one sales row can have 0-many commission beneficiaries attached to it.
e.g. BeneficiaryA gets 2%, BeneficiaryB gets 5% of the "TotalSellingPricePreTax"

I created a many-to-many relationship between FactTransaction and DimCommissionBeneficiary, in the bridge table "IntermediateCommission_CommissionBeneficiary" i added the percentage a Beneficiary gets for the specific sales row and the money (CommissionPreTax)

[Link to cube structure as i cannot post images here yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrJn3.jpg)

The measure "CommissionPreTax" dices by beneficiary but is not affected by any other dimension.
From researching it seems like what i want is a "measure expression" like [FactTransaction].[TotalSalesPricePreTax]*[IntermediateCommission_CommissionBeneficiary].[CommissionPercentage]

like in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sql2k5_mmdim_topic4) under "Measure Expressions and Many-to-Many Dimensions"

Now "measure expressions" are enterprise only, i got mssql standard edition, is there any way to achieve this with a calculated member?